# fill UI of next activity form the current activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

Am working on an android application .Since am a newbie to the Android platform i am bit confusing about how we can manipulate the UI look & feel when there is some complexity.

My problem is on a button click am generating an `ArrayList< Some Object >` and i want to fill the UI of next activity by iterating over this ArrayList. Passing this arrayList into the next activity is not possible throgh `Bundle.putExtras` method since it is not supported, only an `ArrayList< String >` will be supported. At this stage only case i can think creating next activity UI from current activity's button click method iteself.. I think about this a lot..but didn't get an idea to solve this.

So can anyone suggest a nice way to solve my problem.??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various solutions to solve you issue :

**#1** Send an **Array of [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29) objects** from Activity1 to Activity2 through your Bundle

To use this solution, you have to implement **Parcelable** to your class "SomeObject"

**#2** Store your values independently from Activity1 into a **Database** or into **SharedPreferencies** and retrieve these values once you are in Activity2 => more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

**#3** Using a **Singleton** so you can access your data from everywhere

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton _instance;
    private  ArrayList<SomeObject> myList;

    private MySingleton() {
        myList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (_instance==null) {
            _instance = new MySingleton();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public ArrayList<SomeObject> getMyList(){
        return myList;
    }

}
```

So from your activity2, you can retrieve your ArrayList as follow `MySingleton.getInstance().getMyList();`

Answer (score 0):

You can make your "Some object" [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) and then put [ArrayList<Parcelable>](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList<?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable>%29) in your intent.

Comment: can u please give me a brief idea about creating a Parcelable object. I didn't get an idea about that ..dats why.

Comment: Parcelable is just an interface (I linked the documentation for you). So whatever object you are putting in your ArrayList, I'm assuming it's a custom class you wrote, make it implement Parcelable which essentially lets you write and read all the instance variables you need to recreate the object. If your object is too complex instead, then you should consider using SQLite instead (i.e. the previous activity loads the object in the database, passes the ID with the intent, and the next activity reads the object from the database using the ID).

Answer (score 0):

Make that an `ArrayList<Some Object>` with `static` access specifier.